# Falsifiable first order logic formulas

Tags: first-order-logic

My text book claims that the formula: $$\forall x (Px \lor Qx) \rightarrow (\forall x Px \lor \forall x Qx)$$ is falsifiable.

But to me it seems like a tautology / valid formula.

Is my reasoning faulted, or a typo in the book?

Comment: Take $Px$ to be $x=0$, $Qx$ to be $x=1$ and $\forall x$ to range on $\{0,1\}$. Then $\forall x(Px\vee Qx)$ is true, while $\forall xPx$ is false, because for $x$ being $1$ we have $P1$ is false, and $\forall xQx$ is false, as witnessed by $x$ being $0$.

Comment: Try $P=$ "x is even",  $Q=$ "x is odd".

Comment: Is it then so that the $x$ does not need to have the same value for $\forall x Px$ and $\forall x Qx$?

Comment: In other words: x can be odd in the first and even in the second?

Comment: The $x$'s are bound (i.e. quantified) variables, so the formulas on either side don't say anything "about" $x$. Rephrasing the sentence, thinking of the predicates as subsets of the universe $U$, the left side of your implication says "The union of $P$ and $Q$ equals $U$", while the right side is the much stronger statement "Either $P=U$ or $Q=U$."

Comment: Thanks. I still think I am confused by the scope of the bound variables. Can the formula be re-written to include three bound variables, i.e. from  ∀(∨)→(∀∨∀)  to  ∀(∨)→(∀yy∨∀zz).

Comment: @Enthuziast  yes, you can  change bound variables like that and retain logical equivalence, and it makes the semantics somewhat clearer to do so.

Comment: Thanks guys! Really helpful. And I think I understand the concept much better now. Anyone of you want to answer the question? If not I'll answer it myself to be able to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Flan and the other commenting points out the book is right and my reasoning false. I had misunderstood the scope of the bound variables.

Take $Px$ to be $=0$, $$ to be $x=1$ and $\forall x$ to range on {0, 1}. Then $\forall x(Px \land Qx)$ is true, while $\forall x Px$ and $\forall x Qx$ can be false for $x$es being 0.

Thanks for the great comments below the answer. Think they can be useful for many people with a underdeveloped understanding of scope of variables in first order logic...